# Adding content with hooks

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a beginner question: I want to add a product search form to a WordPress theme via a hook. I want to wrap the product search in a `div` in order to be able to style it. How can I add the `div` to the following:

```
add_action('after_main', my_custom_function');

my_custom_funtion() {
    get_product_search_form;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
add_action('after_main', 'my_custom_function');

function my_custom_function() {
    echo '<div class="product-search">' . get_product_search_form( FALSE ) . '</div>';
}
```

Then, anywhere there is a `do_action( 'after_main' )` in your code, this will echo out the search form wrapped in the div. You can change the class, I just added that for the example.

Edit: passed `FALSE` to the function. `get_product_search_form()` echoes by default. Passing `FALSE` returns it instead.

Second edit: You can also use the filter `get_product_search_form` like this:

```
add_filter( 'get_product_search_form', function( $form ) {
    return '<div class="product-search">' . $form . '</div>';
});
```

Comment: Oddly this adds the class after the search form...when I check with dev tools it is added after...

Comment: Ah! I know why. Updated answer.

Comment: @LoraBa I've updated the answer and added a second method that would also work.